# How to fix "Error: Cryptr: secret must be a non-0-length string" in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I encounter this error in my project. When I run `node app.js` or `nodemon app.js` to start the server I get the error `Error: Cryptr: secret must be a non-0-length string`. The error seems to be pointing to a file called cryptr/index.js in node_modules folder. I have deleted node_module and reinstall package.json packages twice but the error remains the same. The complete log of the error is found below.

```
\Users\USER\Documents\projects\src>nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
C:\Users\USER\Documents\projects\node_modules\cryptr\index.js:12
        throw new Error('Cryptr: secret must be a non-0-length string');
        ^

Error: Cryptr: secret must be a non-0-length string
    at new Cryptr (C:\Users\USER\Documents\projects\node_modules\cryptr\index.js:12:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\projects\src\helpers\helpers.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\projects\src\api\routes\admin\auth.js:6:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\projects\src\app.js:17:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Also add you code, not just the error. And look at the https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptr -> `package doc`. May be you are creating `cryptr` object without passing any secret.

Answer (score 1):

Secret key should not be empty

**Error:**

```
const cryptr = new Cryptr(undefined);
```

**Solution:**

```
const cryptr = new Cryptr('SecretKey');
```